# Making Label in Tkinter clickable and opens UrL in a new web browser

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a Tkinter code when a user types a name the URL appears:

I am trying to get the Label which is mySubmit to be clickable and to be opened in a new browser.

I have search several solutions but I didn't was not successful in getting it.

Here is the code:

```
root = Tk()

e = Entry(root, width=50)
e.pack(padx=50)

def open_url(mySubmit):
    webbrowser.open_new(mySubmit)


mySubmit = Label(root, open_url)

def myClick(event=None):
    global mySubmit
    global reply
    mySubmit["text"] = results()
    if e.get() != "":
        search.append(e.get())
    # print(search)
    e.delete(0,"end")
    mySubmit.pack()

def open_url(mySubmit ):
    pass #Open the url in a browser

root.bind('<Return>', myClick)
mySubmit.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, url=mySubmit: open_url(mySubmit ))
```

My question is how to make `mySubmit = Label(root)` clickable to open the url in the new browser

Comment: Why do you have the `url=mySubmit` in your `lambda`? It serves no purpose. Also you might want to take a look at the `webbrowser` library

Comment: @TheLizzard it was a trial which didnt work

Comment: You should pass the text of the label instead of label itself to `open_url()`.  Also you have defined `open_url()` twice and the later one (which does nothing) will be the effective one.

Comment: The webbrowser answer proposed by TheLizzard will work. It's plain python (independent of Tk) so could be called by that button handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mySubmit.pack()


 mySubmit.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: open_url("http://www.google.com"))
```